# cauchy's first theorem on limits of sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Cauchy's first theorem on limits goes like this

If$\ <f_n> $ be a sequence of positive terms and $$ \lim_{\ n\to\infty}\ f_n=l$$ Then
$$ \lim_{ n\to\infty}\ [\ \frac{f_1+f_2+\dots+f_n}{n}]=l$$
Now this is an example of its application.

$Q)$ Find the value of $$ \lim_{\ n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}[1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\dots+\frac{1}{n}] $$ 
$A)$ By cauchy's theorem if $$ f_n=\frac{1}{n} \ and \lim_{\ n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}=0 $$ Then $$ \lim_{\ n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}[1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\dots+\frac{1}{n}]=0$$ I understand this example. Now here is another example and its solution which I found in various texts but I don't understand how can we apply cauchy's theorem to it

$Q)$ Find the value of  $$ \lim_{\ n\to\infty}[\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(n+2)^2}+\dots+\frac{1}{2n^2}] $$
$A)$ Multiply and divide by n 
 $$ \lim_{\ n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}[\frac{n}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{n}{(n+2)^2}+\dots+\frac{n}{2n^2}] $$
Let $$ <f_n>=\frac{n}{(n+n)^2}=\frac{n}{4n^2}$$
Then, $$ \lim_{\ n\to\infty}f_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{4n}=0$$
 By cauchy's theorem
 $$ \lim_{\ n\to\infty}[\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(n+2)^2}+\dots+\frac{1}{2n^2}]=0 $$
As you can see there is clearly a distinction between the first and second question

In th first we have $ 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\dots+\frac{1}{n}$

while in the second one we have $\frac{n}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{n}{(n+2)^2}+\dots+\frac{n}{(2n)^2} $

I see how the first one can be written as the sum of sequence $\frac{1}{n}$

But how can the second one written as the sum of the sequence $\frac{n}{(2n)^2}$
Please help....

Comment: Brother , have you got any leads in this question ?If so, please do share .

Answer (score 3):

Cauchy theorem does not necessarily require positive terms. Further the second problem does not seem amenable to the use of Cauchy theorem. Better express it as a Riemann sum $n^{-2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(1+(i/n))^{-2}$. Now $n$ times the above sum tends to $\int_{0}^{1}(1+x)^{-2}\,dx=1/2$ and hence desired limit is $0$.

Comment: Sir , I have seen the second example in numerous textbooks of real analysis where the author has directly used as mentioned by OP . Please explain us this .

Comment: @HarshVardhanSingh For the second example note that each term depends on $n$ (total number of terms) as well index of the term. Thus the terms can't be written as a sequence and Cauchy theorem can't be applied.

Comment: @HarshVardhanSingh: also I don't think standard textbooks will make a mistake like this. If you have a specific case please ask a new question describing the exact scenario and the community will gladly help you out.

Comment: Thanks @Paramanad Singh

Comment: For a first course in real analysis this method will not be enough if you are not taught riemann integral as a part of the course. Just speaking in the way papers are checked. You have to use concepts that you have learnt in the course. For riemann integral method you have to prove the riemann integrability of $f(x)=\frac{1}{(1+x)^{2}}$ in $[0,1]$. Which is easy provided you have proved that a function is riemann integrable if it is continuous on that closed bounded interval. And then you have to show that you can express it as a product of limits.

Comment: @ArghyadeepChatterjee: well this is a common technique used in typical 10+2 courses in India. At this stage of education students have not even heard of the term "real analysis". But overall I agree that one should not use this method unless one has done some study of Riemann integral.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yeah ofc, I know. But I think the op is talking about college course of real analysis

Answer (score 2):

Answer to the second question.
Observe that for all $n \ge k$,
$$ \frac{1}{2n} \le \frac{1}{n+k} \le \frac{1}{n}$$
Thus,
$$\left( {\frac{1}{{{{(2n)}^2}}} + \frac{1}{{{{(2n)}^2}}} +  \ldots  + n{\mkern 1mu} {\mkern 1mu} terms} \right) \le \left( {\frac{1}{{{{(n + 1)}^2}}} + \frac{1}{{{{(n + 2)}^2}}} +  \ldots  + \frac{1}{{2{n^2}}}} \right) \le \left( {\frac{1}{{{n^2}}} + \frac{1}{{{n^2}}} +  \ldots  + n{\mkern 1mu} {\mkern 1mu} terms} \right)$$
$$\implies \frac{1}{4n} \le \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(n+2)^2}+\dots+\frac{1}{2n^2} \le \frac{1}{n}$$
The answer follows by the Sandwich theorem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to view $n$ as a constant. And that you are taking the average of $n$ things which are itself expressions in terms of $n$. So view it as a sequence $a_{r}=\frac{n}{(n+r)^2}.$

So for example for fixed n say 100. You are taking the average of a quantity say $A=\{\text{marks obtained by student +100}\}$. This is the way you have to view it.

Now the sufficient condition for the theorem to hold is precisely $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n}$ converges. In this case it does. So you can apply the theorem. By which I mean the nth term of an which is a function of n converges.
It's best to view this sequence as a cauchy sequence in order to conceptualize why the theorem is actually working.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $a_n=\frac{n}{(n+n)^2}$. Clearly $\lim \limits_{n\to\infty}{a_n}=0$. Consider the quotient $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^na_n}{n}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{n}{(n+i)^2}}{n}=\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{(n+n)^2}$. By Cauchy's 1st theorem on limits, $\lim \limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^na_n}{n}=\lim \limits_{n\to\infty}a_n$. Substituting $\lim \limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{(n+n)^2}=\lim \limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{(n+n)^2}=0$ which is the case given in your book.